# Vertical swipe/drag gesture in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I need to use the swipeup/swipedown gestures in an Ionic 2 application. When I do

```
<div (swipe)='someFunction($event)'></div>
```

Then my *`someFunction(e)`* is being called, but only on **horizontal** slides -- therefore I'm unable to listen to swipes in up and down directions. *`(swipeup)`* and *`(swipedown)`* seem not to do anything at all. Do you have any idea whether this is possible at all with the Ionic beta?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it?

Comment: @drbishop unfortunately, I just implemented it from the ground up myself :(

Comment: Do you still need a soulution?

Comment: @Duannx as I said, already implemented it from the ground up :(

Answer (score 2):

Ionic 2 makes use hammerjs library to handle its gestures.

They’ve also built their own Gesture class that effectively acts as a wrapper to hammerjs: Gesture.ts.

So you can do your own directive like:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy} from 'angular2/core'
import {Gesture} from 'ionic-angular/gestures/gesture'
declare var Hammer: any

/*
  Class for the SwipeVertical directive (attribute (swipe) is only horizontal).

  In order to use it you must add swipe-vertical attribute to the component.
  The directives for binding functions are [swipeUp] and [swipeDown].

  IMPORTANT:
  [swipeUp] and [swipeDown] MUST be added in a component which
  already has "swipe-vertical".
*/

@Directive({
  selector: '[swipe-vertical]' // Attribute selector
})
export class SwipeVertical implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input('swipeUp') actionUp: any;
  @Input('swipeDown') actionDown: any;

  private el: HTMLElement
  private swipeGesture: Gesture
  private swipeDownGesture: Gesture

  constructor(el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el.nativeElement
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.swipeGesture = new Gesture(this.el, {
      recognizers: [
          [Hammer.Swipe, {direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_VERTICAL}]
      ]
    });
    this.swipeGesture.listen()
    this.swipeGesture.on('swipeup', e => {
        this.actionUp()
    })
    this.swipeGesture.on('swipedown', e => {
        this.actionDown()
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.swipeGesture.destroy()
  }
}
```

This code allows you to do something like this:

```
<div swipe-vertical [swipeUp]="mySwipeUpAction()" [swipeDown]="mySwipeDownAction()">
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update, Ionic now has gesture controls. see

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#gestures

gestures return an `$event` object. You can probably use this data to check whether if it's a swipeup/swipedown event.

[See $event screenshot (since I can't attach images yet ;) )](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTIXR.png)